# Changing max value in SeekBarPreference

Tags: android, xml, max, preferencescreen, seekbarpreference

I can't change max value in standard SeekBarPreference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings">
        <SeekBarPreference
            android:key="seekBarVolume"
            android:max="10"
            android:title="@string/seekbar_volume" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I would like seekbar has a value of:

```
int maxVolume = AudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

I'm trying to change the value in the PreferenceActivity, but I have no idea. 
I stuck at:

> Preference seekBar = findPreference("seekBarVolume");

Is there a way to change max value without using custom seekBarPreference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SeekBarPreference class is hidden for whatever reason. [Source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-l-preview_r2/core/java/android/preference/SeekBarPreference.java) shows that there is a `SeekBarPreference.setMax(int)` method available so it could be possible to use reflection to reach that, but it seems overkill for the task at hand.

I would suggest you to instead use a preset number of steps (such as 10, as your layout suggests) and then calculate the requested volume value using `maxVolume * seekBarValue / seekBarStepCount` as that seems like a safer solution.